# How to optimize my MySQL query with an index

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization, filesort

On this [database](https://launchpad.net/test-db/employees-db-1/1.0.6/+download/employees_db-full-1.0.6.tar.bz2) (employees from MySQL samples) I have to optimize this query using index:

```
SELECT t.title,
       Avg(s.salary) salario_medio
FROM   titles t,
       salaries s
WHERE  t.emp_no = s.emp_no
       AND t.to_date > Now()
       AND s.to_date > Now()
GROUP  BY t.title
ORDER  BY salario_medio DESC;
```

I have already create this index on the "salaries" table:

```
CREATE INDEX to_date_idx ON salaries(to_date);
```

But the `EXPLAIN` gives me those rows:

```
    *************************** 1. row ***************************
    id: 1
    select_type: SIMPLE
    table: s
    type: range
    possible_keys:PRIMARY,emp_no,to_date_idx
    key: to_date_idx
    key_len: 3
    ref: NULL
    rows: 370722
    Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
    *************************** 2. row ***************************
    id: 1
    select_type: SIMPLE
    table: t
    type: ref
    possible_keys: PRIMARY,emp_no
    key: emp_no
    key_len: 4
    ref: employees.s.emp_no
    rows: 1
    Extra: Using where
```

I would like not to use `Using temporary` and `Using filesort`.

INFO:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE salaries;

CREATE TABLE `salaries`
  (
     `emp_no`    INT(11) NOT NULL,
     `salary`    INT(11) NOT NULL,
     `from_date` DATE NOT NULL,
     `to_date`   DATE NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`, `from_date`),
     KEY `emp_no` (`emp_no`),
     KEY `to_date_idx` (`to_date`)
  ) engine=myisam DEFAULT charset=latin1 show CREATE TABLE titles;

CREATE TABLE `titles`
  (
     `emp_no`    INT(11) NOT NULL,
     `title`     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     `from_date` DATE NOT NULL,
     `to_date`   DATE DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`, `title`, `from_date`),
     KEY `emp_no` (`emp_no`)
  )
engine=myisam
DEFAULT charset=latin1
```

Comment: You cannot avoid the sort.  The `ORDER BY` is on a computed column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing the query like this:

```
SELECT t.title,
       (SELECT AVG(s.salary)
        FROM salaries s
        WHERE t.emp_no = s.emp_no AND 
              s.to_date > NOW()
       ) as salario_medio
FROM titles t
WHERE t.to_date > NOW()
ORDER BY salario_medio DESC;
```

This query can take advantage of indexes on `titles(to_date, title, emp_no)` and `salaries(emp_no, to_date)`.

This eliminates the sorting needed for the aggregation.  The query still needs to sort the final results.

Comment: @catmg97 . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should use explicit `join` syntax, rather than implicit. That won't help performance though. What would help, is capturing the result of the function `NOW()` in a variable, that way it only has to be evaluated once, instead of twice per row:

```
DECLARE @dtNOW DATETIME = NOW()

SELECT     t.title
,          AVG(s.salary) salario_medio
FROM       titles t
INNER JOIN salaries s
        ON t.emp_no = s.emp_no
WHERE      t.to_date > dtNOW
       AND s.to_date > dtNOW
GROUP BY   t.title
ORDER BY   salario_medio DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

That may have been a good example 10-15 years ago, but times have changed.

Use InnoDB instead of MyISAM.  Consider using utf8 instead of latin1.  Add an index on titles `(to_date)`.  Get rid of the redundant index on only `(emp_no)` in both tables.  Add `INDEX(title)`.

(I agree that you ought to use the newer `JOIN` syntax.)

And, the `AVG` is likely to be wrong without converting to Gordon's subquery version.  (That construct probably did not exist when the sample was developed.)